# Looking for a 9-patch graphics creation tool

Tags: android, nine-patch

draw9patch seems to be very inconvenient. It takes about 5 minutes to draw all required solid black lines if an image is quite big. It's hard to believe that highly professional developers from Google have created something like this tool.

Are there any better applications? Or do I do something wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have not used it myself, but have heard it is good.

[patchworker](http://digitalsquid.co.uk/patchworker/)

Comment: Never heard of this one before, just tried it out. Works awesome

Comment: Thank you very much, good sir, for this application.

Comment: How to remove black dots?!

Comment: Do you have any tool link for Mac

Comment: If you go to the link, and click "full download list", there's a JAR file version which is stand alone OS independent.  Let me know how you get on!

Answer (score 9):

It shouldn't take 5 minutes. You can hold the shift key and click the first pixel and the last pixel to draw a straight line.

Comment: I'm using Mac OS, while Shift is pressed, you may remove pixels, nothing else.

Answer (score 6):

I found a better option. You can finish your tasks with only drag and drop.

[Nine-patch editor Official Website](http://weblookandfeel.com/nine-patch-editor/)  or [Download Directly](http://weblookandfeel.com/downloads/gpl/ninepatch-editor-1.15.jar)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on a 9-Patch Editor tool for Android devices:

[9 Patch Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.denley.android.ninepatch)